# How to handle no-ascii characters in BigQuery Stream Pipeline?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

How support non-ascii characters in DataFlow pipelines streaming into Google Cloud BigQuery in Python?

This code below try to insert a single line in Big Query, but fail with this error:

> ValidationError: Field string_value encountered non-ASCII string 'This code fail because of \xc3\xa3, a non-ascii character!': 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)

If we remove the 'ã' character from the text, the code will work fine.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import absolute_import
import argparse
import datetime

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions

options = PipelineOptions()
google_cloud_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)


def run(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(pipeline_args))

    (p
     | 'Create the PCollection' >> beam.Create([{
                'timestamp': datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),
                'text': 'This code fail because of ã, a non-ascii character!',
            }])
     | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.Write(
                beam.io.BigQuerySink(
                    'lake.test',
                    schema='timestamp:TIMESTAMP,text:STRING',
                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                )
            )
     )

    p.run().wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: This _might_ help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214993/filtering-out-or-replacing-non-english-characters-from-google-bigquery

Comment: Hello @GrahamPolley, thanks for your comment, but not my case, I want to handle the non-english characters, not filter them, something like `ensure_ascii=False` of json lib.

Comment: Yup, but did you see the 2nd answer about Python 2.7 & 3.x?

Comment: Hello @GrahamPolley, thanks again and sorry to not take full attention. Good news, I will try it. But as we can see [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowPythonSDK/issues/6) and [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1251), the support for Python 3 in GCP and Apache Beam is on experimental version, hope to not face issues. I will try it now and will return soon.

Comment: Cool. Let us know how it goes..

Comment: I only changed the destination table and this works fine for me with Python2.7 and Beam SDK 2.12.0: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFUVY.png). I get the same error with older SDKs such as 2.8.0

Comment: Hello @GrahamPolley, after fall in problems to install python 3.5, the unique python 3 supported by GCP as pointed [here](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1251?focusedCommentId=16789854&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16789854), the code works like a charm. Please, answer the question, and I will mark as correct.

Comment: Hello @GrahamPolley, very interesting, working in both python versions after upgrade the apache beam: `pip install --upgrade apache_beam[GCP]`. The command `pip list` change from `apache-beam  2.5.0` to `apache-beam 2.12.0`.

Comment: Great to hear it's sorted now!